# Group velocity in different dimensions

Tags: solid-state-physics, spacetime-dimensions, crystals

I am given the following equation for the group velocity in one-dimension:

$$v_g = \frac{d\omega}{dk}.$$

In solid state physics one has $-\pi/a \leq k \leq \pi/a$ for a one-dimensional lattice with atoms where $a$ is the equilibrium distance between atoms. But my questions are: Is $k$ in the equation of the group velocity the absolute value of $k$ so rather $v_g = \frac{d\omega}{d|k|}$ and how can we generalize this to 3D for example?

Comment: In 3D, $v_g$ will be a vector quantity, just like $k$

Comment: And what is $k$ in the 1D case? Is this the absolute value?

Comment: no. In the 1D case $k$ is just $k$